# Stata "invalid group specification" error

Tags: stata

I'm trying to run a diff-diff analysis of the included dataset (Excel). It is my understanding that the group() specification requires a dummy variable that defines the control group (0) with the treatment group (0). Thus, I have included variable 'treatment' that does just that.

Stata is throwing me this error no matter what I try, and I can't seem to find a fix anywhere to this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

**Code:**

. didregress (Proposals) (post), group(treated) time(Week)
invalid group specification
None of the groups defined by treated is a control.
r(198);

**Image of dataset:**

[dataset (see treated variable)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCSkG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your treatment group should be specified by `tvar`, not by the `group` option. Type `help didregress` for more information: *"tvar must be a binary variable indicating observations subject to treatment or a continuous variable measuring treatment intensity"*.